# Kotlin:RecyclerView with SoundPool runtime error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am getting a runtime error: `No Value passed for parameter 'soundToInit'`in my SecondAdapter class.
My SecondAdapter is an Adapter to a RecyclerView declared in SecondActivity.

SecondAdapter class:

```
class SecondAdapter(val content:Array<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SecondCustomViewGolder>(){

    //var lessons = arrayOf("Satu", "Dua", "Tiga", "Empat", "Lima", "Enam", "Tujuh",
      //  "Lapan", "Sembilan")

    var soundList = arrayOf(R.raw.sound1, R.raw.sound2,R.raw.sound1, R.raw.sound2,
        R.raw.sound1, R.raw.sound2,R.raw.sound1, R.raw.sound2,
        R.raw.sound1)

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return content.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SecondCustomViewGolder {
        var layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        var cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lesson_row, parent, false)
        return SecondCustomViewGolder(cellForRow)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SecondCustomViewGolder, position: Int) {
        var soundToLoad = SoundEngine()
        holder.soundToInit = soundToLoad.load(SecondViewActivity(), soundList.get(position), 1)
    }
}
class SecondCustomViewGolder(var viewTwo : View, var soundToInit:Int) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(viewTwo){
    init {
        var soundToPlay = SoundEngine()
        soundToPlay.play(soundToInit, 1F, 1F,1,0, 1F)
}
}
```

SoundEngine:

```
class SoundEngine {

    private var soundPool: SoundPool

    init {
        soundPool = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                .build()
            SoundPool.Builder()
                .setMaxStreams(1)
                .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
                .build()
        } else {
            SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0)
        }
    }


    fun load(context: Context, rawId: Int, priority: Int):Int {
        return soundPool.load(context, rawId, priority)
    }

    fun play(soundID: Int, leftVolume: Float, rightVolume: Float, priority: Int, loop: Int, rate: Float) {
        soundPool.play(soundID, leftVolume, rightVolume, priority, loop, rate)
    }
}
```

Please give me some pointers... Thank in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Holder like below

```
class SecondCustomViewGolder(var viewTwo : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(viewTwo) {

    private var soundEngine = SoundEngine()

    fun loadAndPlaySound(soundIdToPlay:Int, priority: Int) {
        val soundToPlay = soundEngine.load(viewTwo.context, soundIdToPlay, priority)
        soundEngine.play(soundToPlay, 1F, 1F, 1, 0, 1F)
    }
}
```

And call it like below:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SecondCustomViewGolder, position: Int) {
    holder.loadAndPlaySound(soundList.get(position), 1)
}
```

Comment: This code is fine. Your actual problem is `you play sound during creation of holder` , which is not correct. You should play sound based on `action` like click on `RecyclerView` item

Comment: Logcat mentions: `2019-12-01 18:57:21.340 24162-24162/com.shamuraq.svgintent6 W/SoundPool:   sample 1 not READY` ... What could it be?

Comment: Please post the new problem in another thread and I will handle it. Keep these thread to specific one problem like `Runtime Error`

Comment: Besides this, do you want to add any action to play sound? or your current approach is ok?

Comment: Asaduzzaman, yes i plan to just play the sound when users click on the different rows on the ewcyclerView itself. Yes, i will post the new problem after Isyak Insya Allah...